# Is there any way to load, minimize and combine different javascript files for different templates in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-pipeline

Now, I put some common javascript files in `PIPELINE_JS` settings. But I also want to load more specific js files based on each individual template. I know I can simply add a `script` tag to include corresponding js files in each template, but that would add additional request to server, which is not a good idea I think. The ideal way I want to do is to use `PIPELINE` to load, minimize and combine different js files based on different templates. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can use a "js" block in your templates and add scripts to it on each page who inherits form your "base", js files are cached anyway

Comment: Ussing [sekizai](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai/) you can commpress them :)

Comment: @lalo pipeline compresses it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is very simple:

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'stats': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/jquery.js',
          'js/application.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/stats.js',
    },
    'logged_in': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/jquery.js',
          'js/collections/*.js',
          'js/application.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/logged_in.js',
    },
    #and so on..
}
```

and while including in the template,

```
{% load compressed %}
{% compressed_js 'stats' %}
```

In another template where you wish to import the other target,

```
{% load compressed %}
{% compressed_js 'logged_in' %} {# or whichever you wish to import #}
```

[Read the documentation](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#template-name) for better understanding.

Comment: Does PIPELINE provide a inheritance structure? I mean as in your example, js/jquery.js should be included in every template, it's a little bit tedious to manually include it in every target.

Comment: In your base.html, have a block section named `pipeline` and then where you want the specific targets, override the block in those specific templates.

Comment: What I want to do is not to override the whole block. I just want to append some new js files to the target in original or base template and make it as a whole new compressed file in pipeline.

Comment: they use `{{block.super}}` at the beginning of the block in the derived html file